# Why does the addition output always 0?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
int getValueFromUser()
{
    std::cout << "Enter An Integer !" << '\n';
    int valueTyped{};
    std::cin >> valueTyped;
    return valueTyped;
}
void _double(int valueToBeMultiplied)
{
    std::cout << "Doubled Is :"<<'\n' << valueToBeMultiplied * 2 << '\n';
}
void add(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << "=" << x + y;
}
int typeInteger(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Enter Your Number" << '\n' << '\n';
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    _double(getValueFromUser()); // Use the () double on the return value of the getValueFromUser()
    int a{}, b{};
    std::cout << "To Add Two Numbers :" <<'\n';
    typeInteger(a);
    typeInteger(b);
    add(a , b);
    return 0;
}
```

The multiplying works fine but the addition , no matter what numbers I type always prints 0 .
Why does it happen ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: Because you never use the return value of `typeInteger()`. `a` and `b` remain unchanged.

Comment: You return the value from `typeInteger` but don't assign ot to anything. If you are going to pass in the value to be changed, then pass it by reference.

Comment: Oh thx people , i thought it will auto assign itself to a and b but it doesnt , anyway thanks !

Comment: Also, you are not allowed to use identifiers starting with an underscore in the global scope. Doing so causes undefined behavior. So use something other than `_double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeInteger()` definition is not suitable to get the value.
After return from the `typeInteger()`, you should save the value into your `a,b` variables.
Please reference this one.

```
int getInputValue(){
    int x;
    std::cout << "Enter Your Number" << '\n' << '\n';
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

a = getInputValue();
b = getInputValue();
add(a , b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that by modifying the input variables you provide to `typeInteger()` you're changing `a` and `b` in `main()` too. That's not true.

You're passing those variables by value. If you want them to be modified, you have to pass them either by pointer or by reference.

The intended behavior would be achieved by changing `int typeInteger(int x)` to  `int typeInteger(int &x)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the addition output always 0?

Because you always pass zeroes as argument:

```
int a{}, b{}; // <-- zero initialisation
...
add(a , b);   // <-- zeroes passed here
```

To fix it, pass something other than zero.